# Interactive workflow with external libraries in Clojure

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have two applications using one shared library. Shared library is included in the `:dependencies` section of Leiningen project configs of the two applications. Code in the shared library is prone to change often, so what i'm doing right now is `lein install` each time there are changes to be taken into account by other two applications.

Some time earlier, when there was one project source tree and the shared library code was not yet separated, interactive coding in the REPL was quite convenient. I could quickly change some library functions and observe the effect on the application code. However, as multiple applications budded out of the original code, it was necessary to include shared code as a dependency in order to avoid code duplication.

Does there exist any workflow that would bring the best of both worlds so to speak - a) provide code separation for dependency management; b) but still retain interactive development capability?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes! It's called checkouts, see the answer marked as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried the approach, and it works. However, i've noticed that REPL restart in the application is required to fetch the changes in the shared library.

Comment: go to the file that changed from the repl and reload the file. I usually just edit the file from there as well. If there are many files to reload you can make a helper function that calls `load-file` on each, or use the component framework though that is a bit of a lifestyle commitment

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt - thanks again! I'm using vim-fireplace, so i just had to `:Require shared-lib-ns` and voila! Upvoting:)